# AJAX fails on second call to url and reloads the page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using AJAX to load certain content, it works on the first request every time but if a second request is made using the same function the site reloads. No errors are shown in Chrome DevTools, the request never shows on the network tab, and the alert() in success never fires, but neither does the one in error.

```
function loadEdit(name,info)
{
    alert(name + ' ' + info);
    $('#mainContent').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#actionContent').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $('#loadingContent').fadeIn('slow', function() {
    $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     cache: false,
     url: '/adm/edit.php',
     data: {"name": name,"info": info},      
     error: function(result, status, err) {
        alert('HTTP ' + result.status + ' Error Encountered: ' + result.statusText);
        alert(result.responseText);
        alert('status: '+status+' error: '+err);
     },
     success: function(data) {
                alert('Success');
                $('#loadingContent').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $('#actionContent').html(data);
                $('#actionContent').fadeIn('slow');

     });
     }

     });
    });
    });
    });
    menuClose();
}
```

Update:
The function is called on a button press on the page, sample below:

```
<button onclick="loadEdit('grps','1')">EDIT</button>
```

Comment: please add more details like call to loadEdit  part...

Comment: is it a form submission that triggers this function ? if so please check if form is intact properly after first submission.. may be form loses class or id which triggers this function.

Comment: How is `loadEdit()` called?

Comment: Sorry! loadEdit() is called on a button press on the page.

Comment: if the page reloads then you loose all the network information if you don't have set 'preserve log'. So make sure you activate this and see if there are new network information that would help (same you can do with the console)

Comment: @Edwin - Thank you, it is on and still provides nothing with the second button press. Preserve is on for both Network and Console

Comment: you can add also `beforeSend(xhr)` and `complete(xhr, status)` to gather more logs. What does the `menuClose();` do?

Comment: is the data from success function is `<button onclick="loadEdit('*','*')">EDIT</button>` or could you please share the html you are getting as data from ajax success

Comment: @Edwin menuClose() just changes some displays to none on the page

Comment: Okay so I'm missing something complete. I remove the .ajax and the page is still reloading.

New function: 
`function loadEdit2(name,info)
{
 //alert(name + ' ' + info);
  $('#actionContent').fadeOut('slow', function() {
   $('#loadingContent').fadeIn('slow', function() {
 
 });
 });
}`

Answer (score 0):

Button was contained within a form and needed type=button added to it to prevent the default action.